# Mysql database duplicating entries

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am learning php and mysql and I'm following a video tutorial. Everything has been pretty easy except I finally ran into an error I cannot find a solution for.

I have a new database with 6 columns:

When I add a test user and then browse users, there are duplicates.

Why am I getting duplicates? How can I fix this? How can I prevent this from happening?

See screenshots:

https://postimg.org/image/6vpiejdob

https://postimg.org/image/jbm88a70b

Sorry, forgot query:

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email_address`, `password`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, 'test', 'test', 'test@test.com', 'test', '1');

Comment: You'll need to provide the code where you insert the user at least

Comment: Your db is not enforcing UNIQUE contraints. Look up unique keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE INDEX(id, email_address);

then figure what to do with errors.

INSERT IGNORE INTO users (id, email_address) VALUES (1, "haha@ha.com"), (1, "haha@ha.com");

you could do more error handling but this would be good idea since a tutorial. I would truncate users table before ALTER TABLE since its just junk data

Comment: Since he is using NULL(for auto_increment), it probably wouldn't be very effective to include id in any unique key other than as the primary.